# battery 'sizzling' noise

Tags: battery-chemistry

car battery making a noise similar to light buzzing ( shorting?) battery just over a year old. car just back from being driven. earth lead removed .noise still there. best described as 'sizzling' 
   alternator was exchanged  2 years  ago . ammeter  shows normal charge/discharging . car. tends to stand in garage for some then between use.  starts /cranks easily. never heard a battery make a nose before .12v well know German  type .wet acid sealed.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like the acid is bubbling creating H2.  Could be dangerous cause it's combustible if it's venting under the hood and there's an open spark.  That's one reason why they have you jump a battery in particular order so you don't spark the terminal and ignite any fumes under the hood.

Did you charge it recently? maybe too fast or over charged? 
I'd take it to autozone and have them do a discharge test.  It might be weak under load which would point to failing battery.